# Помогите получить информацию из браузера в node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookie, websocket, socket.io

Есть ванильный вариант Socket.IO под node.js. Помогите получить COOKIE & GET params, Я ставил кучу библиотек, все попытки оканчивались  Критическими ошибками

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
})
```

Comment: `req.headers` - там есть все что Вам нужно

Comment: Не работает....

Comment: https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-request тогда здесь ищите

Comment: @Дмытрык окей, пасиб...помогло, а как распарсить куки? может есть спец функция....ибо они все идут как строка

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies  - вот